# Power series $\sum \left(1+ \frac{2}{n}\right)^{n^3 + n^2 +1} x^{n^2} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

It is asked to find the interval of convergence of the power series

$$\sum \left(1+ \frac{2}{n}\right)^{n^3 + n^2 +1}x^{n^2}$$

But how should I write this series so it has the form

$$\sum a_n(x-c)^n?$$

With the given formula, I don't know if I can call

$$a_n=\left(1+ \frac{2}{n}\right)^{n^3 + n^2 +1}$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is $a_{n^2}$. For $k$ not a perfect square, you have $a_k = 0$.

Comment: Ok, but how can I show that the radius of convergence is, indeed, $\frac{1}{e^2}$, since $a_n$ diverges?

Comment: Do you know the Cauchy-Hadamard formula?

Comment: No, never heard about this (maybe I just dont know the name)

Comment: Oh, it used $\lim sup$ istead of $\lim$!